# Combining probabilities for multiple individuals

Tags: probability

Take the example question, 'How many individuals will be in state A'.

Let's say I have 5 individuals each with a probability of entering state A.  Those probabilities could be `0.33, 0.87, 0.55, 0.64, 0.17`.  Each probability is independent of the other.

What is the probability that the number of individuals in state A will be 3?  Or perhaps the similar question of 'at least 3'?

Answer (score 1):

**Modeling the system**

I'll use "state 1" to refer to state A in your example, and "state 0" to mean not in state A.

The states of $n$ individuals can be modeled as a random vector $X = [X_1, \dots, X_n]$. Each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli variable that independently takes the value 1 with probability $p_i$ or 0 with probability $1-p_i$.

We can describe any *given* configuration of the system with a binary vector $x = [x_1, \dots, x_n]$ specifying the state of every individual (0 or 1). Because the states of individuals are independent, the probability of a given configuration is:

$$Pr(X=x) = \prod_{i=1}^n Pr(X_i = x_i)$$

**How many individuals in state 1?**

Let $K$ be a random variable representing the number of individuals in state 1:

$$K = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

The probability that $K$ takes a particular value $k$ is the sum of the probabilities of every system configuration where exactly $k$ individuals are in state 1. Let $C_k$ denote the set of all such configurations--that is, the set of all length-$n$ binary vectors with exactly $k$ ones. Then:

$$Pr(K=k) = \sum_{x \in C_k} Pr(X=x)$$

This is the [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), which models a sum of independent (but not identically distributed) Bernoulli variables. The way I've written it is different from the Wikipedia article, but they're equivalent.

**Computational issues**

There are $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$ configurations with exactly $k$ individuals in state 1. This number quickly grows astronomically large. So, computing $Pr(K)$ by explicitly summing over these configurations is infeasible except for small problems. There are various approaches for computing $Pr(K)$ more efficiently; see the Wikipedia article for references.